# Prevent duplicate keys in combined objects, reverse of { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }

Tags: typescript

In typescript I want to create a function which accepts 2 objects, and Object.assigns them to a new object, with type checking that ensures neither object has any of the same keys.

[I tried](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20test1%20%3D%20%7B%20test%3A%201%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20test2%20%3D%20%7B%20something%3A%20'string'%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20test3%20%3D%20%7B%20test%3A%20%7B%7D%7D%0D%0Afunction%20combine%3CT%20extends%20Object%2C%20U%20extends%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20undefined%20%7D%3E(obj1%3A%20T%2C%20obj2%3A%20U)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...obj1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...obj2%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20I%20need%20this%20to%20only%20error%20when%20properties%20on%20test%202%20exist%20in%20test%201%0D%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20combine(test1%2C%20test2)%20%20%2F%2F%20should%20pass%0D%0Aconst%20result2%20%3D%20combine(test1%2C%20test3)%20%2F%2F%20should%20fail) using variaous forms of `k in keyof T` with no success.

```js
function combine<T extends Object, U extends { [K in keyof T]: undefined }>(obj1: T, obj2: U) {
    return {
        ...obj1,
        ...obj2
    }
}
```

The results have not resulted in proper type checking

```js
// setup objects
const test1 = { test: 1 }
const test2 = { something: 'string' }
const test3 = { test: {}}

//  I need this to only error when properties on test 2 exist in test 1

// should pass
const result = combine(test1, test2)

/* Resulting error: 
Argument of type '{ something: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ test: undefined; }'.
  Property 'test' is missing in type '{ something: string; }' but required in type '{ test: undefined; }'.
 */

// should fail and does fail
const result2 = combine(test1, test3)

/* Resulting error:
Argument of type '{ test: {}; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ test: undefined; }'.
  Types of property 'test' are incompatible.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
 */
```

Comment: `<T extends Object, U extends { [K in keyof T]?: undefined }>` produces the weird error: `Type '{ something: string; }' has no properties in common with type '{ test?: undefined; }'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this also works:

```
function combine<T extends object, U extends object>(
  obj1: keyof T extends keyof U ? never : T,
  obj2: keyof U extends keyof T ? never : U,
) {
  return {
    ...obj1,
    ...obj2,
  }
}
```

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20combine%3CT%20extends%20object%2C%20U%20extends%20object%3E(%0D%0A%20%20obj1%3A%20keyof%20T%20extends%20keyof%20U%20%3F%20'arguments%20cannot%20have%20properties%20in%20common'%20%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20obj2%3A%20keyof%20U%20extends%20keyof%20T%20%3F%20'arguments%20cannot%20have%20properties%20in%20common'%20%3A%20U%2C%0D%0A)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20...obj1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20...obj2%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test1%20%3D%20%7B%20test%3A%201%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20test2%20%3D%20%7B%20something%3A%20'string'%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20test3%20%3D%20%7B%20test%3A%20%7B%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20combine(test1%2C%20test2)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result2%20%3D%20combine(test1%2C%20test3)%0D%0A)

Comment: This is perfect, I never realized you could use `keyof T extends keyof U`, in such a way. Very elegant. Definitely accepted answer over mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Forcing myself to organize enough to organize a question, [gave me an idea](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20test1%20%3D%20%7B%20test%3A%201%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20test2%20%3D%20%7B%20something%3A%20'string'%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20test3%20%3D%20%7B%20test%3A%20%7B%7D%7D%0D%0Afunction%20combine%3CT%20extends%20Object%2C%20U%20extends%20Object%20%26%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20undefined%20%7D%3E(obj1%3A%20T%2C%20obj2%3A%20U)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...obj1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...obj2%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20I%20need%20this%20to%20only%20error%20when%20properties%20on%20test%202%20exist%20in%20test%201%0D%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20combine(test1%2C%20test2)%20%20%2F%2F%20should%20pass%0D%0Aconst%20result2%20%3D%20combine(test1%2C%20test3)%20%2F%2F%20should%20fail), which ended up working. I would love to see if someone has a better way though.

```
const test1 = { test: 1 }
const test2 = { something: 'string' }
const test3 = { test: {}}
function combine<T extends Object, U extends Object & { [K in keyof T]?: undefined }>(obj1: T, obj2: U) {
    return {
        ...obj1,
        ...obj2
    }
}

//  I need this to only error when properties on test 2 exist in test 1
const result = combine(test1, test2)  // should pass
const result2 = combine(test1, test3) // should fail
```

`U extends Object & { [K in keyof T]?: undefined}` - extending the Object ended up getting rid of the `has no properties in common with type` error.

Comment: You should probably switch from `Object` to `object` unless you actually want to allow primitives like `combine(test1, "oops")`.